# Add user to group without restart in DEB postinstall

Tags: deb, usergroups, post-install

In my deb-package I add user to 'dialout' group in the `postinst` script:

```sh
usermod -aG dialout $SUDO_USER
```

And I want the new settings to be applied without rebooting:

```sh
newgrp dialout
```

But there is the trouble: `newgrp` logs in user to new session, so we hang while installing (you should enter `exit` in console). So, such command is unsuitable for deb-postinstall.

Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: I hope you are aware that `dialout` is a reserved system group? https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups

Comment: @tripleee of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install script can't change the group of an existing user without logging them out (which it cannot do either). But you can display an instruction to the installing user to suggest they (add themselves to the new group and) `exec sg dialout` if they want to avoid logging out and back in.

Perhaps also notice that `postinst` (or generally any packaging script) cannot invoke commands which require user interaction.  The system should be able to install the package while running completely unattended.